# Debug a python script used with nmake

Tags: python, visual-studio, makefile

I have a Visual Studio project which uses nmake to call a Python file for clean, build, or rebuild. For ex. in VS project properties->Configuration Properties->NMake, for the Build Command Line I would have

....\blah\tools\myBuildFile.py build -arg1 -arg2

There are several python files used with lots of variables and routines so I would like a tool which I could use to step through them. Can anyone suggest a plug-in to Visual Studio which I could use to debug the Python make files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install [winpdb](http://winpdb.org/)
2. Change your command to: `...\blah\winpdb.py ...\blah\tools\myBuildFile.py build -arg1 -arg2`